# How do i change the value of a global variable inside of a if

Tags: javascript

My code does not work, help me please
I want to call the function and let it run **ON**, and when I call it again, the **OFF** will be executed

```js
var on = 1;
function name () {
 if(on == 1){
   alert('ON');
   on = 0;
 }else if(on == 0){
   alert('OFF');
   on = 1;
 }
}
    
name();
name();
```

Comment: It seems that works as expected!

Comment: You are not calling or invoking the function.

Comment: Your code is fine. You just need to call the `name()` function. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better if you use boolean values to avoid confusion

```html
<html lang="es">
<head>
<title>Helping people at StackOverflow</title>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
 // Start global "on" var in false/true state
 var on = false;

 function name (){
  if(on != true){
   // Set on state
   on = true;
   /* Execute "on" code rules

   */
  }else{
   // Set off state
   on = false;
   /* Execute "off" code rules
   
   */
  }
  console.log('Is "ON"?: ',on);
 }
 document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',function(){
  name();
 });
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="btn" type="button" value='Ejecutar'>
</body>
</html>
```